# Get pid from a java subprocess started with xvfb-run

Tags: java, linux, pid, xvfb

I'm trying to get the PID of a java process started with xvfb-run. When started without xvfb-run, I use $! to get the PID of the last backgrounded process but as soon as I use xvfb-run I obviously get the PID of xvfb-run.

Here is the code:

```
#! /bin/bash
logfile=/var/log/SleepTest.log
pidfile=/var/run/SleepTest.pid
command="java -jar /data/test/SleepTest.jar"
( eval exec -c xvfb-run $command < /dev/null >> $logfile 2>&1 ) &
$! > $pidfile
```

If I remove the xvfb-run part in the second last line, everything works ok (except the part that I don't have a display and the program crash). I probably have to play with the "()" and "&" but I'm not an expert.

The program SleepTest.jar is a small program I wrote so I don't have to deal with the real thing. It only sleep for 2 minutes.

For those wondering why I use xvfb-run, it's because the java application I need to start use SWT and I don't have display on my server.

For those wondering why I need the pid of the process, it's because I want to create a init.d file to be able to start|stop|status my application

So is there a simple way to get it ?

Comment: You could use `ps -ef | grep SleepTest.jar | cut ...`.  You will have to tinker with the cut part as it differs across os's.  You may want to verify that the parent pid is the pid you got from $!...

Comment: I'll probably fallback to something like like if I can not get it "cleany". Thanks.

Comment: OK, so with the command:  `ps -ef | grep SleepTest.jar | grep $! | sed -e '1d' | awk '{print $2}' > $pidfile`  I can get it. I'll test to make sure I always get the good one (and only one).  Thanks again...

Answer (score -1):

Run your entire script with `xvfb-run` (e.g. `xvfb-run name_of_script.sh`), and remove the `xvfb-run` from your `eval` line.